# How do I delete some gmail suggested email addresses during composition

Tags: email, gmail

How do I delete some Gmail suggested email addresses during composition.

In the composition window of Gmail web UI, I click TO: and see 6 emails for JohnDoe@domain.com --   5 are not valid anymore and not in my contact list.

Yet all 6 always show when I start typing his name. How to I clear out those email's no longer valid.